# problem running ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 lts from live dvd under windows 7. the first time i was prompt to retrieve the live dvd I did it; the computer restarted, then displayed no live files found. I restarted then inserted the live dvd again. The installation has completed successfully. But everytime I run ubuntu
it displays completing ubuntu installation; and it runs properly only with the dvd plugged in though it is supposed to run without the dvd. how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Is it a laptop with UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing onto other drive? If that's the case go to the Bios, or just the boot-menu, and change the booting order. As you should be directed to the GRUB menu and it should show up with Ubuntu and Windows, sometimes option for kernels.

It's sounds like you are not even loging in onto your session on Ubuntu, that might be because you are ussing running Ubuntu from the LiveDisk.